# Match a variable with an iterater using a vector object array

Tags: c++, sfml

I have an iterator `ic` and a variable `ncount`. I am trying to match `ncount` with the iterator. I would appreciate any help or advice. 
Thanks in advance.

```
for(ic = ackAttacky.begin();ic !=ackAttacky.end())
{
    if(alien[ncount].alienBulletDead == true){
        ic = ackAttacky.erase(ic);
        alien[ncount].alienBulletDead = false;
        alien[ncount].alienFired = false;
        alienBulletCounter -=1;
        cout << ncount << "    " << ackAttacky.size() << endl;
    }
    else
        ++ic;
}
```

Comment: please expand on "match ncount with the iterator";  are you getting an error message.  what types are is "ncount" and "ackAttacky"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `std::distance`?

```
nCount = std::distance(ackAttacky.begin(), ic);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/